# WPS Thread Pool value is Negative

Tags: websphere

In PMI of Websphere Process Server 6.0.5 Thread pool active count value is negative.
When we observed further we found that MDB Thread Pool in having negative value.
Kindly suggest the cause and solution of the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the same issue. This seems to occur when enabling this particular metric at runtime. It appears that the metric is initialized at 0 when it is first enabled, even if there are active threads in the pool, and this will later result in negative values. If you enable it in the static configuration and restart your server it will work correctly.